# MissingMethodException on LinkedHashMap and Map argument types

Tags: groovy

I am running the following groovy script. I am facing the following exception:

> Error while submitting event: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.wipro.core.common.BaseSpec.auditRequest() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [35796698, http://localhost:8090/core-admin/http://curacao1-core-re-md1/, ...]
>   Possible solutions: auditRequest(java.lang.Long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.Map)

I have referred to previous posts on missing method in groovy and did check on the typos or spelling mistakes in my code (found none). Any help is highly appreciated.

```
private String doSyncEvent(def ctx) {
    def result = ""
    def commId = getStringCommId(sql)
    def xmlText = replaceXmlTag(ctx.message, 'CommId', commId)
    def endPointURL = config["core.rest.url"]
    endPointURL = endPointURL + ctx.serviceUrl

    def id = syncRequestCount.getAndIncrement()
    sendForEvaluationWithContext(sql, endPointURL, commId, xmlText, ctx)

    return result;
}

static void sendForEvaluationWithContext(def sql, def url,def commId, def message, Map ctx) {   
    auditRequest(commId, url, message, ctx)
    response = EventPublisher.sendForEvaluation(url, message)
}

static String auditRequest(final Long commId, final String target, final String message, final Map ctx) {
    final LobHandler oracleLobHandler = (LobHandler) AppContext.getBean("oracleLobHandler")
    final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = (JdbcTemplate) AppContext.getBean("testScriptJdbcTemplate")
    final def userId = Utils.getHostName().toUpperCase()
    String msgTrackerAuditSql = "INSERT INTO MSG_TRACKER (COMM_ID,EVENT_TYPE, TIME_SENT) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager = null
    TransactionDefinition txDef = null
    TransactionStatus status = null
    try {
        transactionManager = (PlatformTransactionManager) AppContext.getBean(BeanEnum.transactionManager);
        txDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW)
        status = transactionManager.getTransaction(txDef)
        jdbcTemplate.execute(
                msgTrackerAuditSql,
                new AbstractLobCreatingPreparedStatementCallback(oracleLobHandler) {
                    protected void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, LobCreator lobCreator) throws SQLException {
                        ps.setLong(1, commId);
                        ps.setString(2, userId);
                        ps.setString(3, "TEST_SCRIPT" + "_" + userId);
                        ps.setString(4, target);
                        ps.setString(5, "ASYNC");
                        lobCreator.setClobAsString(ps, 6, message);
                        ps.setString(7, ctx.get("eventType",""));
                        ps.setTimestamp(8, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    }
                }
            );

        transactionManager.commit(status)

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        transactionManager.rollback(status)
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Read the error again...

> No signature of method: static com.wipro.core.common.BaseSpec.auditRequest() is applicable for argument types: (**java.lang.String**, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [35796698, http://localhost:8090/core-admin/http://curacao1-core-re-md1/, ...] Possible solutions: auditRequest(**java.lang.Long**, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.Map)

This is telling you that you're trying to call the `auditRequest` method with a `String` as the first argument, when the method signature specifies that the first argument should be a `Long`.

Comment: Sometimes it's depressing to see how people don't scour the internet. In this case, however, the OP didn't even read or analyze the error message, amazing.